# Where are programming language functions in memory located?

Tags: c++, c, function, memory, function-pointers

When a function is called, lets say in c++, is it located in a specific place in memory since function pointers exist? If so where exactly? How about classes? Is there memory stored aside for class definitions?

Comment: _"If so where exactly?"_ Text/code segment of your program. Have a lookup for linker maps.

Comment: If it had no location, you could not call it!  The mechanics of compiling, linking, relocating and loading are architecture/OS-specific and too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, functions are located in a specific place in memory. In the context of Virtual Memory (opposed to physical caches), they are stored below the Heap and below a section called the Data (global variables) in a section called Text. All of this is loaded up when the executable is read; this is all done in binary, which is one-to-one with assembly, so you'll never see this in your C code. However, if you know the processor well, you can sometimes still manipulate it into reading from the code section in your code. It may cause a segfault however, and generally you cannot write to the code section.

Just like pointers to variables, function pointers point to a place on the overall stack (see [this helpful site](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/02a-Memory_Layout_And_The_Stack.php)). There is actually a register devoted to pointing to exactly which instruction the program is currently executing.

Class definitions and member functions also have a specific place on the stack; I'm not entirely sure, but I believe they go in Data.

Comment: youre not sure about class definitions?

Comment: @ArmonSafai No I'm not sure; the class abstraction makes things complicated. For example, should member functions go in the code section? We can leave a pointer to them in our class section, wherever that may be, but that's an unnecessary jump, they might as well be inlined (which isn't exactly the same as the inline keyword as far as I know).

Comment: Alright well thank you for your response, you are sure about the functions though right?

Answer (score 0):

All of this may be wrong, it is not my specialty. But as far as I know...

A function at runtime is a position in the executable that a "lower" part can call, altering the stack... never mind, I'll not try to explain this any further.

A class is not stored in memory. It is completely conceptual. Say you have the following structure.

```
struct idk
{
    char* name;
    int index;
    void* data;
};
```

Well, `new idk` at runtime doesn't actually look at some kind of definition to know what to allocate. Instead the compiler figures everything out so that the end result is that `new idk` turns out to be the conceptual equivalent of `new char [sizeof(idk)]`, though that is not taking into account alignment and packing. Anyway, so references also don't have any form of table to look at for what variables are where, they rather are also determined at compile-time, so that `int n = idk_thing.index` would perhaps act like `int n = *((int*)(&idk_thing + sizeof(char*));` and so on.

And of course, a class's storage is implemented almost identically to that of a structure, and any class-specific functions are just plain old functions that, again, the compiler sets up a certain way so that it modifies variables in the class by accessing the storage of an instance of the class. I assume that this is done by passing a pointer to the storage to the function, which accesses that block of memory with offsets depending on what variable it is working with (just the same as what I was saying about structures).

Now, as for function pointers, assuming I am at least on the right track with the compiled equivalent of functions, I'd say that function pointers are just numbers to represent the location in the loaded executable that is the starting place for a function, just as a `char*` is a number meant to represent the location of a `char` in memory.

Answer (score -1):

As for classes, in C++ (and all OOP languages, if that matters) they are typically created on the heap. Though C++ **can** create it on the stack if you ommit the `new` keyword, but that's generally not recommended because classes tend to be resource-heavy, but it means that you'll have a memory leak if you don't explicitly `delete` it.

For function pointers, they're usually just pointers in the stack pointing to seperate code blocks in read only memory.